# Files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited error in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a todo app where I use hilt,room,mvvm structure, but when I run the application, an error appears. What is the reason of this ?

**AppModule_InjectRoomDatabaseFactory***

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.iebayirli.mvvmbase.service.NoteDatabase;
import dagger.internal.DaggerGenerated;
import dagger.internal.Factory;
import dagger.internal.Preconditions;
import dagger.internal.QualifierMetadata;
import dagger.internal.ScopeMetadata;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
import javax.inject.Provider;

@ScopeMetadata("javax.inject.Singleton")
@QualifierMetadata
@DaggerGenerated
@Generated(
    value = "dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor",
    comments = "https://dagger.dev"
)
@SuppressWarnings({
    "unchecked",
    "rawtypes"
})
public final class AppModule_InjectRoomDatabaseFactory implements Factory<NoteDatabase> {
  private final Provider<Application> appProvider;

  public AppModule_InjectRoomDatabaseFactory(Provider<Application> appProvider) {
    this.appProvider = appProvider;
  }

  @Override
  public NoteDatabase get() {
    return injectRoomDatabase(appProvider.get());
  }

  public static AppModule_InjectRoomDatabaseFactory create(Provider<Application> appProvider) {
    return new AppModule_InjectRoomDatabaseFactory(appProvider);
  }

  public static NoteDatabase injectRoomDatabase(Application app) {
    return Preconditions.checkNotNullFromProvides(AppModule.INSTANCE.injectRoomDatabase(app));
  }
}
```

**Error**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error.  That's a warning that you shouldn't edit that file, because it's generated at compile time and your changes would be overwritten when you compile again.  It doesn't prevent you from running the app.  If you actually want to edit that file, you need to change the file its generated from to do what you want rather than edit the generated code.

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is that it cannot be Generated, so there is probably a problem with room integration.

Comment: It is a generated file, Room works via code generation.  Unless you mean you can't regenerate it for some reason, in which case you need to be showing us your module and the error that occurs when you try to build.